# Имеет ли здесь смысл детерминированная функция?

Tags: sql, функции, oracle, oracle11g

В запросе используется такое условие:

```
t1.field = replace(t2.field, <Сложная конструкия вычислений по тексту, insrt, substr и т.д.>)
```

Соответственно, для каждой строки это значение вычисляется.
Планирую эти вычисления перенести в детерминированную функцию вида:

```
func(p_t2_field) <Сложная конструкия вычислений по тексту, insrt, substr и т.д.> return
```

Чтобы не вычислять, а сразу же брать из кеша нужный вариант (если он до этого был использован в качестве аргумента функции).

Имеет ли это смысл в этом конкретном случае?

И еще попутный вопрос, можно ли как-то узнать, какие варианты уже содержатся в кеше?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, имеет смысл, если можно гарантировать, что конструкция:

```
<Сложная конструкция вычислений по тексту, insrt, substr и т.д.>
```

**всегда** вернёт одинаковый результат для одного и того же значения параметра `p_t2_field`.
То есть, результат вычисления заведомо избавлен от побочных эффектов, например, национальных настроек, именений переменных сессии или её контекста и т.д.
В [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1080746) один из примеров такoго побочного эффекта.

Простой рабочий пример, вместо ожидаемых 9 сек. получим:

```sql
create or replace function slowfun (n number) return number deterministic is
begin
    dbms_lock.sleep (1);
    return n;
end; 
/

SQL> set timing on rowprefetch 15
with data (n) as (
    select mod (rownum, 3) n
    from dual connect by level<=9)  
select slowfun (n) n from data
/

9 rows selected. 

Elapsed: 00:00:03.079
```

> Можно ли как - то узнать, какие варианты уже содержатся в кеше?

Нет такой возможности нет. Этот кеш имеет очень "короткую жизнь" так, что не только последующее выполнение того же запроса, a даже последующий фетч не увидят его.

То есть, снижение колличества записей возвращаемых в фетч может свести эффективность кеширования на нет (во многих инструментах `arraysize`):

```sql
SQL> set arraysize 1 rowprefetch 1
SQL> /

9 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:09.22
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё до того как детерминированные функции стали начииная с 10g использовать *hash table* для кеширования результатов функции, это было воможно с SSC (*scalar subquery caching*). То есть, вызов функции в запросе должен выглядеть так:

```
--where t1.field = func (t2.field) --no caching
where t1.field = (select func (t2.field) from dual) --caching
```

Его преимущество, что хеш не сбрасывается для каждого фетч и действителен для всего запроса.

Такой воспроизвидимый пример:

```sql
create or replace function slowfun (n number) return number is 
begin
    dbms_lock.sleep (1);
    dbms_output.put_line ('n='||n||' at '||to_char (sysdate, 'mi:ss'));  
    return n;
end; 
/
create table tnum as 
    select mod (rownum, 3) n from dual connect by level<=9  
/
set timing on serveroutput on arrays 1 rowprefetch 1
select n from tnum where n = slowfun (n)  
/
9 rows selected.

n=1 at 59:30
n=2 at 59:31
n=0 at 59:32
n=1 at 59:33
n=2 at 59:34
n=0 at 59:35
n=1 at 59:36
n=2 at 59:37
n=0 at 59:38
Elapsed: 00:00:09.25

select n from tnum where n = (select slowfun (n) from dual) 
/
9 rows selected.

n=1 at 01:57
n=2 at 01:58
n=0 at 01:59
Elapsed: 00:00:03.09
```

**Важно:**
Kлючевое слово `deterministic` опущено в декларации функции только для примера. Это не только хинт для SQL интерпретатора, в первую очередь оно служит для документации того, что функция действительно детерминированна и должна остаться такой при при её последующих изменениях. Обязательно включите `deterministic` в декларацию функции.